# Как взять значение в форме из Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Привет всем.

Задание. Вычисление выражения. Например, на странице есть

> `аргумент1 
>   оператор
>   аргумент2
>   ответ`

Оператор должен быть в виде выпадающего списка. Как взять значение в форме из Javascript? Именно значение оператора, например, если знак "+", то прибавить аргумент1+аргумент2, если знак минус, то аргумент1-аргумент2

```js
function f1(obj) {

  var a = obj.st1.value;
  var h = obj.st2.value;
  var k = obj.list.value;
  k = parseInt(k);
  switch (k) {
    case 0:
      var s = "ошибка!";
      break;
    case 1:
      var s = (a + h);
      break;
    case 2:
      var s = (a - h);
      break;
    default:
      alert("error!");
  }

  document.write("Выражение равно: ", s);

  return s;
}
```

```html
<p>Вычисление</p>
<form name="forml">
  arg1: <input type="text" size="7" name="st1">
  <hr>
  arg2: <input type="text" size="7" name="st2">
  <hr>
  <select name="list" size=1>
    <option value="1">+</option>
    <option value="1">-</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value=Вычислить onClick="f1(forml)">
</form>
```

`getElementById` получает элементы из формы, мне надо наоборот - получить элементы из Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить актуальное значение выбранного элемента либо присвоить новое значение выбранному элементу, надо пройтись по дереву DOM. В самом простом случае:

```js
var s = document.getElementsByName('selection')[0];

for (var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) {
    if (s.options[i].value == "newValue")
        s.selectedIndex = i;
}
```

```html
<select name="selection" onchange="alert(this.value);">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Как обратиться к выбранному элементу?
if(this.value=="1")
c=a+b;
вот так?

Comment: Проще в зависимости от выбранного элемента (selectedIndex) выполнять требуемую операцию в switch.

Comment: обошлось без цикла

Answer (score -1):

Всё просто.

```
function x(b) {
return b
}
a = document.querySelectorAll('input');
a[0].value = x('всё, что хочешь, возвращай');
```